# Recommendation textbooks on D-module

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, partial-differential-equations, advice, d-modules

I am going to take part in a seminar on D-module and applications, the textbooks that will be used are :  [D-modules, Perverse Sheaves, and Representation Theory](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-0-8176-4363-8), and [A Primer of Algebraic D-Modules](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521559081)

However, I am a beginner in this theory and I found hardly to understand the main road in these books.

Could you please suggest me some other textbooks that are easier or more intuitive?

Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, if you want a question made community wiki, please flag it for moderator attention. Tagging it (community-wiki) does not have the desired effect.

Comment: [Cross-posted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103082/) please don't post both sites, here and on MO, in order to avoid duplication of efforts. If you do post the same question on several sites, please provide links.